# Hibernate. how to read query results not mapped?

Tags: hibernate

im really new in hibernate and java, and there are something i dont understand how to solve.(im trying to mod an existing code)

i have a table called ct0016582213
it has a mapping file: Track.hbm.xml
and an entity class: Track.class

until here all is normal, when i do a query to extract some values inside the table i can read that values inside tables thanks to the hibernate mapping.

But my problem is that i'm trying to do some custom SQL queries and i want to read the resulting table values but i got a [Ljava.lang.Object;@15df563 instead a real value.

```
//part of the code
session = HibernateUtils.getSession();
session.beginTransaction();

String mql= "SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(createtime,'%Y-%m-%d') as fecha, FORMAT((MAX(mileage)- MIN(mileage)),1) as kilom FROM ct0016582213 where createtime between '2015-06-02%' and '2015-06-30%' GROUP BY  DATE_FORMAT(createtime,'%Y-%m-%d')";

SQLQuery query1 = session.createSQLQuery(mql);
List kilom = query1.list();
str=str + "<item>"+ kilom.get(0)+"</item>";
str=str + "<item>"+ kilom.get(1)+"</item>";
session.getTransaction().commit();
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/xml");
out.write(str);
```

this give a two columns as result but when i want to show some values shows instead a [Ljava.lang.Object;@15df563.

and im confused because if the query has just one column as result i can read and show the real values inside the resulting query, for example if i use the next sql query i can read for example a 2015-06-05 as result.

```
String mql= "SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(createtime,'%Y-%m-%d') as fecha FROM ct0016582213 where createtime between '2015-06-02%' and '2015-06-30%' GROUP BY  DATE_FORMAT(createtime,'%Y-%m-%d')";
```

how should i read the values in the resulting table when there are more than one column to get the value and not the object?

can i avoid the mapping? if not..how to map a table that is a result of a query? how can i read the values

did i explanined well my problem?, :-)
thanks for the help

Comment: If i understand correctly you need to cast first item from list `kilom` to java.util.Date and second to another object propably Integer but im not sure what returns `format` function in sql.

Comment: hi, not really, the SQL query works fine..  the resulting table has two columns, the problem is when i try to read the values because it return Ljava.lang.Object;@15df563 not the real value,  i thinks is because there are no hibernate mapping of that resulting table, my question is how to read the real values without mapp that resulting table in hibernate.... is possible?